# Free poker game database

Tags: data-request, research, database

I'm looking some free data to make data mining research about texas holdem poker game.

What I'm expecting is some kind of log file containing information about what players had in hand, how they betting, and what actions they took.

What I already found are following links but actually doesn't satisfied me:

https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/881/publicly-available-poker-stats - in this topic there are mendtioned tree links:

1.http://web.archive.org/web/20110205042259/http://www.outflopped.com/questions/286/obfuscated-datamined-hand-histories - probably the closest log list that I'm looking for, but lack of information about cards, only actions provided

2.https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Poker+Hand - containing only information about cards, no actions mentioned

3.http://poker.cs.ualberta.ca/irc_poker_database.html - I downloaded data, but have no idea how to read this

What I actually looking for would be combination of information provided in links 1 and 2

I haven't found any others sources of data over the internet. It don't have to be data from recent years or anything, Just to have big amount of instances.

Any help will be appreciate.